# ANTLR Grammar for parsing a text file

Tags: parsing, antlr, grammar, antlr4

I'm driving crazy trying to generate a parser Grammar with ANTLR.
I've got plain text file like:

```
Diagram :   VW  503 FSX 09/02/2015  12/02/2015  STP
Fleet   :   AAAA

OFF     :       

AAA     05+44   5R06            
KKK     05+55   06.04   1R06            5530
ZZZ     06.24   06.30   1R06            5530
YYY     07.53           REVRSE      
YYY     08.23   9G98            5070


WORKS   :       

MILES   :(LD)   1288.35 (ETY)   3.18    (TOT)   1291.53
```

Each "Diagram" entity is contained beetween "Diagram :" and the "(TOT) before EOF.
In the same plain txt file multiple "Diagram" entity can be present.

I've done some test with ANTRL

```
`grammar Hello2;

xxxt : diagram+;
diagram : DIAGRAM_ini  txt fleet LEGS+ DIAGRAM_end;
txt : TEXT;

fleet : FLEET_INI txt;
 num : NUMBER;
// Lexer Rules

DIAGRAM_ini : 'Diagram :';
DIAGRAM_end : '(TOT)' ;
LEGS : ('AAA' | 'KKK' | 'ZZZ' | 'YYY') ;
FLEET_INI :  'Fleet :';
TEXT : ('a'..'z')+ ;
NUMBER: ('0'..'9') ;
WHITESPACE : ( '\t' | ' ' | '\r' | '\n'| '\u000C' )+ -> skip ;`
```

My Goal is to be able to parse Diagrams recursively, and gather all LEGS text/number.

Any help/tips is much more than appreciated!
Many Thanks

Regs
S.

Comment: Crazy? And what is your problem? it seems that your lexer grammar is ambigious. "AAAA" should be token "TEXT" while "AAA" is "LEGS". Maybe you should implement parser tokens like "swallow_to_semi" or "swallow_to_newline".

Comment: Hello, maybe it's because I'm newbie to this concept, but I don't understand your suggestion sorry. Why "AAAA" should be token into "TEXT"? I think I need to tokenize Diagram and Fleet strings, no? Also I don't get what you mean by "swallow_to_semi" sorry... Thanks for your help.

Comment: When you have an input like "Fleet   :   AAAA" then lexer will produce tokens: [FLEET_INI("Fleet :"), LEGS("AAA"), TEXT("A")]. Because the LEG is listed before TEXT and matches 1st three "A"s. Just try to debug generated parser code, and you will see that the rule "fleet" will fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest not parsing the file like you did. This file does not define a language with words and grammar, but rather a formatted text of chars:

- The formatting conventions are rather weak
- The labels before the colon cannot serve as tokens since they may reappear in the body (AAA (=label) vs AAAA (=body)
- The tokens must be very primitive to fit this requirements

**Solution with ANTLR**

You need a weaker grammar to solve this problem, e.g.

```
grammar diagrams;

diagrams : diagram+ ;

diagram : section+ ;

section : WORD ':' body? ;

body : textline+;

textline : (WORD | NUMBER | SIGNS)* ('\r' | '\n')+;

WORD : LETTER+ ;

NUMBER : DIGIT+ ;

SIGNS : SIGN+ ;

WHITESPACE : ( '\t' | ' ' )+ -> skip ;

fragment LETTER : ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z') ;

fragment SIGN : ('.'|'+'|'('|')'|'/') ;

fragment DIGIT : ('0'..'9') ;
```

Run a visitor on the Parsing result

- to build up the normalized text of body
- to filter out the LEGS lines out of the body
- to parse a LEGS line with another parser (a regexp-parser would be sufficient here, but you could also define another ANTLR-Parser)

**Another alternative:**

Try out Packrat parsing (e.g. [parboiled](https://github.com/sirthias/parboiled))
 - it is (especially for people with low experience in compiler construction) more comprehensible

- it matches better to your grammar design
- parboiled is pure java (grammar specified in java)

Disadvantages:

- Whitespace handling must be done in Parser Rules
- Debugging/Error Messages are a problem (with all packrat parsers)